# QlikView: Counting With Set Analysis

Tags: qlikview

I have following expression which counts saved persons:

```
=Count({1<Saved={'Yes'}>} Surname & Forenames)
```

I also have follwing expression which counts died persons:

```
=Count({1<Saved={'No'}>} Surname & Forenames)
```

However, for some persons there is no data, but I want to count that persons as well:

```
=Count({1<Saved -= {'No', 'Yes'}>} Surname)
```

However, this last expression gives me 0 as a result, although there are null values in the Saved field. How can I count every surname which has any value in the Saved field other than YES and NO (count should include everything except YES and NO, even Null values)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a table object you can uncheck "supress when value is null" and it should show when using `count(Surname)`.

If you want it to show in a text object you can probably use something like:

```
=Count({1} if(IsNull(Saved), Surname))
```